# Can't ifdown eth0 (main interface)

Tags: debian, networking

I can't `ifdown` an interface on Debian 6.0.5:

```
user@box:/etc/network$ sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
SIOCADDRT: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.

user@box:/etc/network$ cat interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0 
allow-hotplug eth1 

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.254

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
```

As requested by marco:

```
user@box:/etc/network/$ cat /run/network/ifstate 
lo=lo
eth1=eth1
```

Comment: What does `/run/network/ifstate` contain?

Comment: I have updated my question with the contents of this file, eth0 isn't in there. A quick "Google" is telling me the meaning of this file (as I haven't accessed it before), I think I can see where the problem is :)

Comment: @Marco; This has indeed fixed my problem, if you post this as an answer I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Check the contents of the file `/run/network/ifstate`. `ifup` and `ifdown` use this file to note which network interfaces can be brought up and down. Thus, `ifup` can be easily confused when other networking tools are used to bring up an interface (e.g. `ifconfig`).

From [man ifup](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/8/ifup/)

> The program keeps records of whether network interfaces are up or
>   down. Under  exceptional  circumstances these records can become
>   inconsistent with the real states of the interfaces. For example,
>   an interface that was  brought  up  using ifup and later
>   deconfigured using `ifconfig` will still be recorded as up.  To fix
>   this you can use the `--force` option to force `ifup`  or `ifdown` to
>   run configuration or deconfiguration commands despite what it
>   considers the current state of the interface to be.

Comment: To add to this answer, I had to add `eth0=eth0` to `/run/network/ifstate` to get it to recognize the interface and configure it properly. This answer helped point me to the file, but stopped short of suggesting that addition, which is what solved my similar problem.

Comment: @DavidParks Are you sure the interface is marked as `auto` in `/etc/network/interfaces`? It should appear in `/run/network/ifstate` without the need to manually modify the file.

Comment: `--force` was the answer for me; it turned out `ifup` didn't bring the interface up in the first place because of a failing command in `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d`; lucky me having network at all!

Answer (score 35):

`ifdown` is a high-level program which does a lot of things you might not need. Additionally, it isn't available everywhere. The more portable way might work for you:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

If you then can't `ifup` it, you likely have some configuration problem. Manually bringing it up with `ifconfig eth0 up` probably isn't the right thing in that case. On Debian, `ifup` is a binary executable, so you'd probably have to `strace` it to figure out where it's getting hung up:

```
$ sudo strace -e open ifup eth0
```

That will tell you which files `ifup` is opening while it works, which might clue you into the problem.

On other systems (e.g. RHEL and derivatives) `ifup` is a shell script, so it's a lot easier to debug:

```
# sh -x `which ifup` eth0
```

Running a shell script with `sh -x` makes it print every line it runs, so you can trace the execution.

Comment: A cracking answer, but Marco has found the problem. I did try `sudo ifconfig eth0 down && sudo ifconfig eth0 up` which would flap the interface up and down but I was trying to manually trigger an if-up script I have been writing and that wasn't doing it. After updating my /etc/network/run/ifstate file, ifdown/up works now. Thanks for your info though! :)

Comment: Forgot to say, great idea with the -x option! Thanks!

Comment: `ifdown` is a high-level program which does a lot of thing that you might need. `ifconfig eth0 down` is more portable and can always be run, but it doesn't perform the cleanup tasks that `ifdown` might do.

Comment: I don't mean to suggest that you use `ifconfig` all the time, avoiding `ifup/down`. I suggested it only as a troubleshooting step. As I understand the problem, it turned out to be a *result* of using `ifconfig` instead of `ifup/down`, thereby confusing the high-level mechanisms. But, I didn't know that when I posted my answer.

Comment: Possibly obvious, but don't do what I just did which was `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` on a remote machine . Make sure you do `sudo ifconfig eth0 down && sudo ifconfig eth0 up`

Answer (score 24):

I've seen this before when ethX wasn't properly configured in 
`/etc/network/interfaces`. This needs something like:-

```
auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Even with an improperly configured `/etc/network/interfaces` file, you can still bring down eth0 with:

```
$ sudo ip link set eth0 down
```

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. I forgot to append it to `auto`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone struggling with this problem:

I checked the file ifstate."interface-name" at /run/network.

It was empty so I included "interface-name"(eth0) into ifstate."interface-name" file at /run/network.

Answer (score 2):

Add `eth0=eth0` to `/run/network/ifstate`. This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

What I found helped me is to call the `rm` command to remove the lock file within `/run/network/`

Do `ls -la` and you should see a hidden `.ifstate` file or something under that name.

Remove that and then try: `ifdown && ifup`

If you're worried you might break something just make a copy of that file outside the directory and remove the one inside the directory.