# Networking service won't restart

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I have the following networking problem in Ubuntu server:

When I try to restart the service networking I have the following error:

```
# systemctl restart networking
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And when checking the status:

```
# systemctl status networking
* networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           `-50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-08-05 11:49:42 CEST; 4 days ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 1789 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1773 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1789 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

The log say:

```
# journalctl -xe
Aug 09 14:12:38 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: Stopped Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 09 14:12:38 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has begun starting up.
Aug 09 14:12:38 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ifup[4487]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Aug 09 14:12:38 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ifup[4487]: Failed to bring up ens160.
Aug 09 14:12:38 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 09 14:12:38 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

This is my network configuration:

```
# ip a | grep ens
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.20.252.15/24 brd 172.20.252.255 scope global ens160
3: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.254.51/24 brd 192.168.254.255 scope global ens192
```

The file:

```
# cat /var/run/network/ifstate.ens192 
ens192
```

It's OK, but the file /var/run/network/ifstate.ens160 is empty, so:

```
# cat /var/run/network/ifstate
lo=lo
ens192=ens192
```

Therefore the commands `ifup` and `ifdown` ens160 won't work, that's normal because of the empty *ifstate.ens160* file.

Of course, if I add manually ens160 inside of the */var/run/network/ifstate.ens160*, then I can restart properly the networking service, but this happens every time I restart the server, so this is not a solution.

Also, if I execute manually:

```
ip addr flush dev ens160
```

then `ifup` and `ifdown` will work and networking service will work too, but after reboot the original situation remains.

I've seen similar issues in SE, like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50602/cant-ifdown-eth0-main-interface) but neither of the answers seems to solve my problem.

Which is the cause of this issue and how can I fix that definitely?

EDIT:

NetworkManager service is also running, but it is not managing the involved network interfaces:

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Even if I stop the NetworkManager service, the networking service won't reboot.